# Do Ash Blocks absorb water, or is that just me? Or is it because of the Underworld?

Tags: terraria

Do Ash Blocks absorb water, or is that just me? Or is it because of the Underworld?

I was in the Underworld trying to prepare a small pool of water to dump lava into, but the ash block seemed to absorb the water I poured on it.

I guess that's the Water Evaporation effect of the Underworld?

Even though water somehow got deeper than where I am and managed to not evaporate?

Does water only evaporate in the Underworld when touching Ash?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All water evaporates in the Underworld. However, due to the often laggy nature of big bodies of water, sometimes you can glitch a puddle into the Underworld without it evaporating. However, once it settles, if you mine a block from the bottom of that puddle, it will begin to evaporate.

Comment: Note that the "puddle" can be *quite big* if you use **big** bodies of water (ie. pouring an ocean via multiple hell-evators).

Comment: @NahynOklauq You can also instantly settle all this water by savequitting and coming back to the world. I use this to turn the lava in an area to obsidian, so I don't have to make a walkable floor myself or find lava walking boots.